# Writer inserting unwanted newline character

Tags: c

I have 2 C functions that interact with one another. The first a writer function takes an int n and writes "Hellohello" n number of times. The reader function reads whatever is input to it, and every 50 characters inserts a newline character.

My current dilemma is that when I have a number of characters that is a factor of 50 my reader is putting an extra newline character in when I do not want it to. I have tried multiple different ways to remedy this and nothing I have attempted has worked as of yet. What I'm providing is my reader code without any of my attempted fixes as well as an example of what the problem is.

I do have to use getchar and putchar, I understand that there would be easier ways if I wasn't using them but it is unfortunately a must. Any assistance as to how I should approach this or something I should have thought about are greatly appreciated.

reader code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int count = 0;
  char c;
  while (c != EOF)
  {
    c = getchar();
    if (count == 50)
    {
        putchar('\n');
        count = 0;
    }
    putchar(c);
    count++;
  }
}
```

example output:

```
[88] [cbutc1@courses2016:~/csc412]$ writer 10 | reader1
HellohelloHellohelloHellohelloHellohelloHellohello
HellohelloHellohelloHellohelloHellohelloHellohello

▒[89] [cbutc1@courses2016:~/csc412]$
```

edit: clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply changed the if statement that was checking the count to include a check for newline characters. This remedied the problem that was occuring.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int count = 0;
  char c;
  while (c != EOF)
  {
    c = getchar();
    if ((count == 50) && (c != '\n'))
    {
        putchar('\n');
        count = 0;
    }
    putchar(c);
    count++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read (getchar) a newline you print a newline (putchar).

Also, 'c' should be declared 'int'' so it is big enough to hold EOF properly.

Also the value of 'c' is undefined the first time through the loop and you print "EOF'", use:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { …
```

Additionally, you should use `int main ( void ) { …`

And the C language does have "classes", only functions.